# Draw solid and dashed line in one context

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I want to draw a dashed line and a solid line in one context. But if I draw a dashed line first, the second line is also a dashed line. So how to clean up `context.setLineDash`? I tried `context.beginContext()`, it doesn't help.

Here is the code:

```
if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    // The first line
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 20, y: rect.height/2)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.width - 40, y: rect.height/2)
    context.move(to: startPoint)
    context.addLine(to: endPoint)
    context.setLineWidth(1)
    context.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [4, 4])
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.progressDashLineColor.cgColor)
    context.strokePath()
    // Second line
    let startPoint1 = CGPoint(x: 20, y: rect.height/2 + 5)
    let endPoint1 = CGPoint(x: rect.width-120, y: rect.height/2)
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.mainColor.cgColor)
    context.setLineWidth(5)
    context.move(to: startPoint1)
    context.addLine(to: endPoint1)
    context.setLineCap(.round)
    context.strokePath()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the line dash to an empty array before drawing your solid line.

```
context.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [])
```

From the `CGContext` documentation:

> Pass an empty array to clear the dash pattern so that all stroke
>   drawing in the context uses solid lines.

[Documentation Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/2427130-setlinedash)